# How to retain CheckedTextView Checked status after Orientation changes

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I've created an application that uses recyclerView and adapter. I want to use onSaveInstanceState to save the state of my checkedtextview upon orientation it was refreshed. How can I retain the state of it? I want to use onSave and onRestore Instances.

```
import android.net.wifi.rtt.CivicLocationKeys
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.os.PersistableBundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
import android.os.Parcelable
import android.widget.CheckedTextView
import android.net.wifi.rtt.CivicLocationKeys.STATE

import androidx.annotation.NonNull


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    //TODO declare the grocery list as an ArrayList?
    val grocerList: ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf("Cilantro", "Beans", "Cheese",
        "Oil","Tomato", "Salt", "Pepper", "Flour", "Garlic",
        "Lime", "Onion", "Rice", "Cabbage", "Avocado")

    //TODO implement the recyclerview
    //TODO implement the adapter for the recyclerview IN A SEPARATE CLASS

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        val rc : RecyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewGroceryList)
        rc.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        val rcAdapter = GroceryAdapter(grocerList)
        rc.adapter = rcAdapter
        Log.d("MainActivity","onCreate()") //onCreate()
    }

    //TODO override all the activity callbacks, don't forget to call super!
    //onStart()
    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        Log.d("MainActivity","onStart()")
    }

    //onResume()
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        Log.d("MainActivity","onResume()")
    }

    //onPause()
    override fun onPause(){
        super.onPause()
        Log.d("MainActivity","onPause()")
    }

    //onStop()
    override fun onStop() {
        super.onStop()
        Log.d("MainActivity","onStop()")
    }

    //onDestroy()
    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        Log.d("MainActivity","onDestroy()")
    }

    override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)


    }

    override fun onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState: Bundle) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState)
        

    }
}
```

This is the adapter that I use to take in the string array. I want to save the state of my recyclerView so when it orientates my checkedTextView tick did not remove.

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.CheckedTextView
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
import android.os.PersistableBundle

import android.os.Bundle




class GroceryAdapter(private val gList: ArrayList<String>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<GroceryAdapter.GroceryViewHolder>() {

    // create new views
    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): GroceryViewHolder {
        // inflates the card_view_design view
        // that is used to hold list item
        val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
            .inflate(R.layout.grocery_list, parent, false)

        return GroceryViewHolder(view)
    }

    // binds the list items to a view
    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: GroceryViewHolder, position: Int) {
        // sets the text to the textview from our itemHolder class
        holder.gItem.text = gList[position]
        holder.gItem.setOnClickListener {
                if (holder.gItem.isChecked) {
                    holder.gItem.isChecked = false
                } else holder.gItem.isChecked = !holder.gItem.isChecked
        }

    }
        /* return the number of the items in the list */
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return gList.size
        }

        // Holds the views for adding it to text
        class GroceryViewHolder(ItemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(ItemView) {
            val gItem: CheckedTextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.groceryCTV)
        }

}
```

Comment: You need to create a data class that represents each item of data to display in your list. Adapting a list of Strings is inadequate because you have no way to store the state of individual list items. Not just after a screen rotation, but even if you scroll something off the screen and back on, it will lose state.

Answer (score 0):

Have a boolean array/list of the form

`val checkedState=mutableArrayOf<Boolean>(false,false,false,false)`

considering there are 4 checkboxes.

Now use the checked listener to manipulate the checkedState variable.

(if the 2nd and fourth are checked the value would be false,true,false,true)

On reorientation simply use the values in the checkedState to assign the value as checked or not